# Graph label issue with displaying Korean

Tags: r, histogram, cjk

I'm currently trying to display Korean in my graph (a simple histogram), which I've generated in R.
But it won't display Korean correctly.
Could someone please help? Many thanks in advance!

```
hist(df$var, main = "abc가나다", xlab = "def마바사")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the default font — Helvetica — which is missing Hangul glyphs. You can either configure a font which has these [via `par(family = …)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/par.html).

Or you can use the ‘[ragg](https://ragg.r-lib.org/)’ package to plot to a graphics device which supports font fallback: this means that the graphics device will automatically select a font that supports the glyphs you’re using.

With ‘ragg’, you can do the following:

```
capture = ragg::agg_capture()
hist(df$var, main = "abc가나다", xlab = "def마바사")
plot_data = capture()
dev.off()
plot(as.raster(plot_data))
```

Admittedly, this is a bit cumbersome. However, for plotting *to a file*, using ‘ragg’ is no more effort than using base R: you just replace the device, e.g. `agg_png` instead of `png`.

Comment: Hi, I am using R 4.1.2 and this does not work...would you know an alternative solution? @Konrad Rudolph